# mongodb keyfile permission denied

Tags: mongodb, permissions, ubuntu, access-control

I configured in `/etc/mongod.conf` to enforce keyfile access control, in `security` option enabled, `keyFile` is `/root/dbtest.key` (the absolute path of keyfile). I already gave the ownership to `mongodb` user by `chown`, and granted `400` permission on that `dbtest.key` file.

But `mongod` keeps failing to start, after checking log, the error is `Error reading file /root/dbtest.key: Permission denied`. After checking the ownership and permissions on `dbtest.key`

[image]

Which means I already granted correctly. So I don't know at which step I did wrong

Comment: What O/S are you using and how are you starting the MongoDB server? What are the permissions for the `/root` directory where the keyfile currrently lives? The `mongod` process will need to to have read permission for the directory as well as the keyfile. I suspect you should use a path other than `/root`, since this is normally the root user's home directory with access restricted to the `root` user.

Answer (score 0):

@Stennie Comment was right! I have just moved my keyfile from my home user `/home/user/keyfile` to a directory where `mongodb` is owner: `/var/lib/mongodb/keyfile`.
Also remember keyfile must have 400 permissions and be owner and group of mongodb:
chmod 400 keyfile
chwon mongodb:mongodb keyfile